# How is the Reminders app UI created?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, user-interface

I am building an app that is basically comprised of a table view. I would very much like to adopt the look of iOS 5's Reminders app. I don't really have a good idea of how such a UI is built (what it is comprised of). I am only concerned with the main (initial) view.

Do you think that the text "Reminders" is the header for the embedded table view? If so, is it possible to embed a button, like the "+" button" to the right of "Reminders" in the header? What type of button is that?

The table cells are surrounded by a solid line but the inner-cells are separated by dotted lines. Is this accomplished via custom drawing?

I apologize in advance for what I am sure are basic questions. I am not new to Objective-C but I am not at all familiar with iOS UI basics.

Thank you,
MP

Answer (score 2):

You would probably be better off crating a custom button and label for the header of your app and then using a table view with a [UIColor clearColor] background.

The look and feel of the table view cells are created in the cellforrowatindexpath method in the tableview's controller.  Google around for a tutorial on styling a table view cell.  There are lots of examples and lots of ways to do it.

I would take the time to learn a bit about the iOS UI elements, it will make your life much easier as you continue to develop apps.

Answer (score 1):

The text "Reminders" is not a header but "X Completed" is a header. If you want to make Reminders like app, simple way to develop is

1) Create view with UIImageView background (black color) with three buttons at the top.

2) text "Reminders" and + button is another uiimageview

3) dump tableview

4) customize cell should have dotted line at the bottom and horizontal margin.